# How to serialize an object with jakcson and add dynamic field to it

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have to following class:

```
public class CustomClass {

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    private boolean value;
    @JsonProperty("OtherObjects")
    private List<OtherObjects> objects;
    @JsonProperty("Num")
    private int num;
    @JsonIgnore
    public String dynamicParameterKey;
 }
```

On deserialization I get this object, as part of nested objects that each has it rules of deserialization and serializations.
however on serialization I need this object to add another field with "dynamicParamterKey" as it's key and "value" as it's value

I can't add a field in compile time as the key is dynamic.

So what I need to do is to serialize the object as regular and add this custom field.

This class is a part of a whole bunch of classes so I need it to be encapsulated as much as possible (not using a custom deserializer and add it to the ObjectMapper), and I can use treeMap or something because it is a part of a larger json that is sent to me.

How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation and collecting parts from a lot of sources I've came up with this solution:

You need to make you class implement [JsonSerializable](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializable.html) so you can make a custom serialization.

now because you want to use the default serialization and only add to it you need to use the [BeanSerializerFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerFactory.html) to do that.

so it will look something like this:

```
public class CustomClass implements JsonSerializable {

    @JsonProperty("Value")
    private boolean value;
    @JsonProperty("OtherObjects")
    private List<OtherObjects> objects;
    @JsonProperty("Num")
    private int num;
    @JsonIgnore
    public String dynamicParameterKey;


//We do this so Jackson will know how to serialize with dynamic parameter key
@Override
public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
    gen.writeStartObject();

    //use default serializer
    JavaType javaType = provider.constructType(RegulationAnswer.class);
    BeanDescription beanDesc = provider.getConfig().introspect(javaType);
    JsonSerializer<Object> serializer = BeanSerializerFactory.instance.findBeanSerializer(provider,
            javaType,
            beanDesc);
    serializer.unwrappingSerializer(null).serialize(this, gen, provider);

    //add custom fields
    gen.writeBooleanField(dynamicParameterKey, isChecked());

    gen.writeEndObject();
}

@Override
public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        serialize(gen, serializers);
}
}
```